# In-app billing doesn't work:IAB helper is already set up

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have setup In-App Billing for the first time using the new v3 API. When I press the button to purchase, my app crashed, the log is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is already set up.
```

What is the cause of this error? Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you call `IABHelper.startSetup()` at least twice. This method must be called only onсe. Check out your code and remove second call, which is most likely resides in you `OnClickListener`.